# How to convert Single quote to Apostrophe(Curled Quote) in XsLT

Tags: xml, xslt, translate, apostrophe, single-quotes

I am trying to translate the below(Single Quote to Apostrophe):

Input: Toulouse'wer

Output: Toulouse’wer

I tried using the following 2 commands:

`<xsl:variable name="apos" select='"&apos;"'/>
<xsl:variable name="rsquo">&#39;</xsl:variable>
translate(text(),$apos,$rsquo)`

This command is still giving single quote(') as an output.

`<xsl:variable name="apos" select='"&apos;"'/>
<xsl:variable name="rsquo" select='"&rsquo;"'/>`

Here, in this command I am not able to declare the second variable(rsquo) in xslt.

Please Advice.

Comment: Please edit the question property, lost data.

Comment: Going by your example. you want to convert apostrophe to a single quote, not the other way round as your title suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `$rsquo` wrong. `&#39;` is the apostrophe (same as `&apos;`). The code for the right single quotation mark is `&#8217;`. So you end up replacing the original apostrophe with itself.

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="translate(text(), $apos, '&#8217;')"/>
```